# Kahler vs Floyd Rose

Tags: guitar, tremolo-system

This video makes it out to be that you are either a a fan of floyd or a Kahler man. Why is that so? What exactly makes them different enough that using both would be impractical?

Comment: This is a 30-minute video. I'm not going to watch the whole thing. Could you state the exact position, in minutes and seconds, that this point is discussed?

Comment: Don't they ask and answer that very question in the video? 2:05

Comment: I'd like a little more detail if possible. Maybe people with more experience could tell me more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of my floating trem guitars are Floyd Rose licenced, but one is a Kahler.

For pretty much all purposes, they behave exactly the same. The functional usability is the same despite the different way the string ends lock.

The great advantage of the Kahler is that there is no need to clamp the strings in the block (over time I have had 2 blocks shatter on Floyd Rose trems - which is annoying right before a gig!) as the ball end sits at the back of the trem and the strings feed all the way through.

Aside from that, they feel almost identical, both in pull ups and divebombs. Stability is similar too.

So the basic premise of the question is wrong - in the video, you can clearly hear, "It's what I learned on, I guess" which seems to be the only reason.